# Good practice for watermarking/trademarking a website

Tags: web-development, website-design

When developing a website for a client, is it considered normal/proper etiquette to include an inconspicuous link to the developer's own website at the bottom of the client's website?

In case that wording is too weird, say I'm developing a website for a company. Would it be respectable if I included my own logo, unobtrusively, in the footer of their website?

Answer (score 1):

Including your own logo or a text link to your website can't be done unobtrusively. However, a text link is more normal than a logo.

In any case, this kind of thing must be contractual.